# Python List Comprehension - numpy array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-science, list-comprehension

The shape of the NumPy array created from a list comprehension is incorrect when I use numbers above 9 Please help me correct it and also explain why this is happening. Please find below the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

sep_payment = pd.DataFrame({"Creditor":['Axis','RBL_CC','KOTAK_PL','KOTAK_CC','Cashe','SBI','HDFC_Jumbo','HDFC_CC','SCB','Tata Capital','Flex_Salary'],"Priority":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11],"Payment_Status":['Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending'],"Credit_Status":['Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending','Pending'],"Payment_Date":['-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-','-'],"Time Taken in Days":[2,5,5,2,5,2,5,5,5,5,2]})

# List comprehension Looped with range 9 NO ERRORS | Output (9, 6)
subb= sep_payment.iloc[1].to_string(index=False).split()
subb
subb2 = [sep_payment.iloc[i].to_string(index=False).split() for i in range(9)]
subb2
data= np.array(subb2)
print(data.shape)

# List comprehension Looped with range 10 ERROR in THE SHAPE printed | Output (10,)
subb= sep_payment.iloc[1].to_string(index=False).split()
subb
subb2 = [sep_payment.iloc[i].to_string(index=False).split() for i in range(10)]
subb2
data= np.array(subb2)
print(data.shape)
```

[Dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMWYs.png)

[list comprehension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIxUo.png)

Comment: Hi Jenish, welcome to SO. A quick tip, please copy the code and paste it into the question using code blocks for others to help. Its impossible to see the images and assist you. Please read [ask] and take a quick [tour] to know how you can improve your post to get the maximum out of Stack Overflow!

Comment: Hi @AkshaySehgal the code is added Please assist

Comment: do check the answer below. The issue with your code is due to the space that is occurring in "Tata capital". I have added an explanation and a solution to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are facing is due to the space that is occurring in your data for the row for bank `Tata Capital`

#### In part 1:

Your first code is breaking this string (for the row) into 6 parts each since there is no space occurring between any of the tokens in the 6 columns. This results in a numpy array of (9,6) shape which is 9 rows, and 6 columns as expected.

```
subb2 = [sep_payment.iloc[i].to_string(index=False).split() for i in range(9)]
subb2

[['Axis', '1', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '2'],
 ['RBL_CC', '2', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['KOTAK_PL', '3', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['KOTAK_CC', '4', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '2'],
 ['Cashe', '5', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['SBI', '6', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '2'],
 ['HDFC_Jumbo', '7', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['HDFC_CC', '8', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['SCB', '9', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5']]
```

#### In part 2:

In the second part, however, you are breaking all the other rows into 6 parts, BUT one of the rows into 7 parts thanks to the space in `Tata Capital`. When you try to convert this into a numpy array, it creates an array with 10 rows as expected, but 1 column since each of the objects in this array is a list object and counted as 1 item.

This is because a `ndarray` in numpy NEEDS to have the same elements for each axis.

```
subb2 = [sep_payment.iloc[i].to_string(index=False).split() for i in range(10)]
subb2

[['Axis', '1', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '2'],
 ['RBL_CC', '2', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['KOTAK_PL', '3', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['KOTAK_CC', '4', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '2'],
 ['Cashe', '5', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['SBI', '6', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '2'],
 ['HDFC_Jumbo', '7', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['HDFC_CC', '8', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['SCB', '9', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5'],
 ['Tata', 'Capital', '10', 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', '5']] #<-- CHECK THIS ROWS
```

---

### Solution:

Just directly use `df.to_numpy()` instead of what you are doing to get the numpy array..

```
data = sep_payment.to_numpy()
data

# array([['Axis', 1, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 2],
#        ['RBL_CC', 2, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 5],
#        ['KOTAK_PL', 3, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 5],
#        ['KOTAK_CC', 4, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 2],
#        ['Cashe', 5, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 5],
#        ['SBI', 6, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 2],
#        ['HDFC_Jumbo', 7, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 5],
#        ['HDFC_CC', 8, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 5],
#        ['SCB', 9, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 5],
#        ['Tata Capital', 10, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 5],
#        ['Flex_Salary', 11, 'Pending', 'Pending', '-', 2]], dtype=object)

data.shape
#(11, 6)
```

Comment: Thank you  that solved it :-)  @Akshay Sehgal